# BASH Simple - Run for all folders

Tags: bash, directory

I want to run a bash code, that I have written, in all subfolders (where it has been "called").
The code I have written is simply named "all", and when I run it individually in each folders, it runs with no problems.

But when I run it with this code, it doesn't run (it runs, but gives errors like - files not found).

```
for D in *;do   
    all
done
```

I got the mistake!!! I need to enter each folder in order to run the code "all". How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I have already made the code executable.

Comment: "all" is bash function and should have parameter $D? Or it's a code in the folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about

```
for D in `ls`; do
    $D/all
done
```

EDIT:

If you need to enter each folder:

```
for D in `ls`; do
    cd $D
    ./all
    cd ..
done
```

EDIT (spaces + directories only):

```
for D in `ls -d`; do
    cd "$D"
    ./all
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: I got the mistake!!! I need to enter each folder in order to run the code "all". How do I do that?

Comment: It gives me something like that:

21a/all: No such file or directory. - for all folders

21a is a correct folder as the other, but in this way it looks for a folder "21a/all" , while it should open the directory and RUN "all"

Comment: Actually doesn't. Try to pass a subfolder containing space in it's name. Also `ls` returns files, you should at least test it to not to do `cd file`

Comment: Yep, you're right. You helped me get to the solution, but I kept using the "*", so the final code that runs perfectly was that one:


`for D in *;do
    cd $D
    all
    cd ..
done´ 


Thanks for the constant help. I appreciate it. Sadly I don't yet have enough reputation to "Vote Up" for your answer...

Comment: This is not a proper solution! It will report a lot of errors like `bash: cd: myprogram.sh: Not a directory`. `ls -d` returns just a `.` dir. `ls -d *` works better, but space problem is not handled.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to run `ls` or `find` to get the list of the files in a folder. There is a pure bash solution for this. You may try something like:

```
for D in *; do
  [ -d "$D" -a -x "$D/all" ] && "$D/all"
done
```

This works well even if the directory contains spaces. The `ls` and `find ...` fails in that case (if a directory is `a b` then `D` will be `a` and then `b`). Also the `find` also returns `.` dir. You can avoid this using `find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`. The `find` has an advantage: it discovers hidden directories as well (`.somedir`). With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) this can be forced using `.*`, but then `.` and `..` dirs have to be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`

```
for D in `find . -type d`; do
   "$D"/all
done
```

This will find every subfolder recursively! And will not follow symlinks (it's default behaviour of find)

You can specify the max depth of recursion with the parameter `maaaxdepth`

```
for D in `find . -type d -maxdepth 1`; do
   "$D"/all
done
```

This will only take the subfolders in current pwd

EDIT by future me: Don't use that!

Better way: Globbing

```
for i in * 
do 
  [[ -d $i ]] && ./"$i"/all
done
```

Comment: This will return `.` dir as well. Correctable with `-mindepth 1`. And works badly if the dir contains space.